# Request param list of long

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

eventIdsToDelete    ["24616342","24615878"]I am trying to send list of Long values to the Spring controller but I am getting 400 Bad Request error. So I am guessing my request mapping signature is incorrect.

My jQuery AJAX call

```
var myList = [24616342,24616201,24616310];
$.ajax({
  url: '/myApp/path/toController',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {myList: JSON.stringify(myList)},
  success: function(response) { ... }
});
```

My request mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myApp/path/toController", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody boolean doSomething(Model model, @RequestParam List<Long> myList)   
{
    System.out.println(myList);
    return true;
}
```

In firebug console I am seeing URL being called but in post tab I am seeing parameters as

```
myList ["24616342","24615878"]
```

I tried by changing request mapping parameter to

```
List<String>
```

and it working fine. But I want to have request mapping method type be String.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved with following changes

(a) jQuery Call

```
 data: {myList: myList},
```

(b) Controller Method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myApp/path/toController", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody boolean doSomething(Model model, @RequestParam("myList[]") List<Long> myList)   
{
   System.out.println(myList);
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try @RequestBody instead

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myApp/path/toController", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody boolean doSomething(Model model, @RequestBody List<Long> data)   
{
    System.out.println(data);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I make it working with @RequestParam itself but I have to have String type instead of long type. Please see edited post. How can I have parameter as Long type list instead of String type.